# Cisco 1800 drops link to ADVA

Tags: cisco, wan

I'm having a problem getting a Cisco 1841 connected to an ADVA WAN box provided by TWTelecom. They've given me instructions to force the fasteternet0/0 100 full duplex on interface 0/0, which I have done. When I boot the cisco, there is link and activity during boot, then the Cisco port lights black out while it resets the ports, and once they come back on, the link doesn't remake.

If I connect a laptop to the ADVA, the link makes and it can communicate. Laptop NIC properties show a 100mb connection. If I connect a laptop to the fastethernet0/0, the link makes and it can communicate. Lights on 0/0 show 100 mb and full duplex connection.

The config file for that interface is very basic.

```
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.2.2 255.255.255.0
 speed 100
 full-duplex
 service-policy output EGRESS
!
router rip
 version 2
 network 10.0.0.0
 no auto-summary
!
```

What would keep the ADVA and Cisco from making a successful link once the Cisco completes its boot?

Comment: without knowing the IOS version of the router or having the output of `show run` - the odds of getting a useful answer aren't terribly high.

Comment: Ok, can you also add the result of `show int fa0/0` when it's plugged in

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "ADVA" is, but I'm guessing it's metro-ethernet hardware.  Most metro-e setups don't do auto-negotiation at all. `speed 100` and `duplex full` should be disabling autoneg, but who knows what Cisco's doing.  The `keepalive` checks could also be killing the link.

If "auto" works for speed and duplex, then go with it. :-) (that's what your laptop is doing.)

Answer (score 2):

> They've given me instructions to force the fasteternet0/0 100 full duplex on interface 0/0, which I have done. When I boot the cisco, there is link and activity during boot, then the Cisco port lights black out while it resets the ports, and once they come back on, the link doesn't remake.

Based on this description, I'm going out on a limb and suggesting that your static `speed` and/or `duplex` settings are causing the issue... please remove both of them from `FastEthernet0/0`.  If that doesn't work, try different ethernet cables (both crossover and straight) to the Adva.

Answer (score 1):

The ADVA device is used by the provider as a point of demarcation and to ultimately terminate the WAN link.   If it is a multi port ADVA then you might want to ensure you are plugged into the correct port, usually 1-4 for 100Mb and port 5 used as the Gig port, therefore double check with the provider which port has been provisioned.

As Mike Pennington suggested then try removing speed & duplex config on the cisco router or alternatively try to auto negotiate if that doesn't prove succesful.

Lastly, the ADVA does has some intelligence in that it can carry vlans so you might want to check with the provider if anything in this respect has been configured as standard across the wan link. I've seen instances of needing to configure a sub-interface on the router that corresponds with the vlan id set on the wan link, albeit this can likely depend upon the service type and Provider Edge routers being used.